# Is there any way of clearing the launcher activity from App's Activity history programmatically by setting some intent flag?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way of clearing the launcher Activity programmatically from activity's history stacktrace ??

I have this Activity A(launcher activity) & Activity B

From 
A->B , is there anyway of erasing A once B has started .

Comment: You mean when you press back button then main activity not open.

Comment: what exactly you want..some more clarity is needed..

Comment: I want to erase launcher activity , by setting intent flag . But since  I don't start launcher activity from intent programmatically , so I am caught , how to set something like FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY in launcher intent ..